# Methods for solving $ Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find $null(A) $ by solving for $ Ax=0$:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &-1  & 2 & -1\\ 
-1 & 0 & -1 &2 \\ 
2 &-4  &6  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

I convert to reduced row echelon form:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  & 1 & -2\\ 
0 & 1 & -1 &-1 \\ 
0 &0  &0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

and use this to write:

$x = \alpha \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} + \beta
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

but the solutions in the book describe solving it using back substitution, while only converting $A$ to upper triangle:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &-1  & 2 & -1\\ 
0 & -1 & 1 &1 \\ 
0 &0  &0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Are they using a faster method? I so could you describe it?

Answer (score 1):

When you reduce to RREF first, there is no back substituting needed. If you only reduce to upper triangular, then there is some back substituting left to do. Just convert back to a system of equations:

$$
x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 - x_4 = 0 \\
-x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0,
$$

and solve for the leading variables in terms of the free variables, starting from last row and back substituting appropriately:

First, from the second equation,

$$
x_2 = x_3 + x_4,
$$

and then substituting into the first equation

$$
x_1 = x_2 - 2x_3 +x_4 = -x_3 + 2x_4,
$$

which will give the same set of solutions as what you got. They are only slightly different methods of solving the problem, so it is just a personal preference how you do it. I prefer to do it like you did, do the work to put the matrix in RREF first, so that there is no back substituting needed later.

Comment: Understood. I agree that RREF is easier, but it helps to understand both methods. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the system $$\begin{cases}x-y+2z-w=0\\-x-z+2w=0\\2x-4y+6z=0\end{cases}$$ You get the subspace of dimension $1$ defined by
$$x=y=3z=2z\text { where}\space w=2z$$